# Mocking Inbound Email Headers in Test Class (In-Reply-To or References)

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service

We have a custom email handler in apex. With the new changes upcoming to remove Thread IDs (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000355168&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1), we are migrating our logic to utilize the new method `getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders`.

While the logic works, I am struggling to write unit tests appropriate for this. Specifically, I am trying to mock an InboundEmail with an In-Reply-To or References header (which is what the `getCaseIdFromEmailHeaders` method uses to get the Case Id) however those values are encoded on real emails and I don't know how to replicate that encoding.

Has anyone come across a way to test this? Again specifically trying to mock an inbound email header to test matching/non matching against an existing case.

Thanks!

Comment: think of the problem the same way that HttpMocks are used for callouts. You'll want to create an interface that has two concrete implementations - one in your production code and one injectable by your testmethod

Comment: I guess my question is specifically though how to "mock" or even create the implementation that contains this header. I need to test if it has the case ID header it matches to existing case, otherwise we have other cascading logic to match on other items.

Comment: can you use [edit] and show your testmethod illustrating how you are mocking the inbound email?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am also encountering this error, and Salesforce documentation is unsurprisingly silent about how to do this.

I suspect creating a test outbound email might create headers that you can then use on a test inbound email? I have no idea though.